# Proof verification: Norm of a functional

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, solution-verification, continuity

I'm trying to prove that for $X=C([0,1])$ and the continuous linear functional on $X$ defined as $\phi(f)=\int_0^1(t-\frac{1}{2})f(t)dt$, $\|\phi\|\leq\frac{1}{4}$, there exists no such continuous function $f\in B_X$ so that $\phi$ attains its norm.

My approach is this, because $(t-\frac{1}{2})$ changes from negative to positive on the interval and $f\leq1$, then $f$ must also be negative in the first half and positive on the second half and because its continuous, then $f(0)=0.$

By the definition of continuous functions for $\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0:\forall x\in(\frac{1}{2}-\delta,\frac{1}{2}+\delta):|f(x)|<\epsilon.$

We will now use this inequality for calculating the integral
$$\int_0^1(t-1/2)f(t)dt<\int_{(0,1)\setminus(\frac{1}{2}-\delta,\frac{1}{2}+\delta)}(t-\frac{1}{2})f(t)dt+\int_{\frac{1}{2}-\delta}^{\frac{1}{2}+\delta}(t-\frac{1}{2})\epsilon dt=\int_{(0,1)\setminus(\frac{1}{2}-\delta,\frac{1}{2}+\delta)}(t-\frac{1}{2})f(t)dt\leq0,$$
where the final inequality is using $f\leq1$ and the fact that $(t-1/2)$ is an odd function on the integrating interval, therefore such $f$ cannot exist and $\phi$ doesn't attain its norm.

Comment: How does this prove that thr norm of $\phi$ is not attained?